# How to write in the equivalent but terse code, maybe using by Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, nested

How to write in the equivalent but terse code, maybe using by Linq??
This code:
`var sectionAttributePairs = new List<SectionAttributePair>();`
where `SectionAttributePair` is my own class

`entityAttributes` is `AttributeMetadata[]` type

```
List<AttributeMetadata> attributesBeyoundSection = entityAttributes.ToList();
foreach (var pair in sectionAttributePairs)
{
    foreach (var attr in entityAttributes.ToList())
    {
        if (pair.Attribute.Contains(attr.LogicalName))
        {
            attributesBeyoundSection.Remove(attr); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any attempt of your own?

Comment: Without knowing *any* of the datatypes, this is impossible to answer. Please write a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide us with more information about the code ... like the variables' types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `attributesBeyoundSection` a `List<T>`? Then you can use [`List.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var matchingAttributes = entityAttributes
    .Where(attr => sectionAttributePairs
        .Any(pair => pair.Attribute.Contains(attr.LogicalName)));

attributesBeyoundSection.RemoveAll(matchingAttributes.Contains);
```

Note that the class must either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or implement `IEquatable<T>`(best is both always). Otherwise `Contains` would just compare references.

Comment: yes,   it is `List<AttributeMetadata> attributesBeyoundSection = entityAttributes.ToList();`